# Environment Model

Tags: scheme, environment

Given the following environment diagram, I am having a hard time to create a code that triggers a computation that is described by the diagram given in the below image.

[image]

edit: what I tried as I understand:

```
            (define foo (lambda(goo)
                (let ...)))

          (define goo (lambda (args)
                 (goo args)))

          (foo (goo ((lambda(y)
                 (+ y 5)))))
```

Comment: SO expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Comment: @Barmar I tried my best please help.

Comment: @WillNess https://stackoverflow.com/a/5848238/9557460

Comment: you should bring the explanations from the PDFs to the question itself. SO questions are supposed to be self-sufficient. you can't force people to read the PDFs to be able to understand your question.

Comment: Is "goo" unbound in E1? there are no arrows